# Firebase cloud function not running?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have written the bellow code to detect when a comment has been added to the DB and then to respond by updating a timeline node the issue is that it does not actually update. **Why is it not working?**

```
    export const onCommentAdded = functions.database
.ref('/Comments/{receiverUID}/{postID}/{mediaNum}/{commentID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const uid = context.params.uid
  const newCommentUID = snapshot.child("UID").val()
  console.log(newCommentUID, " the comment")
  return addNewCommentNotif(uid, newCommentUID) 
})

function addNewCommentNotif(uuid: string, newCommentUID: string) {

  //NotifTimeline/uid/NewNotif (someuniqueVal)/commentID
  const randID = Math.floor(100000000 + Math.random() * 900000000);
  const notifTimelineRef = admin.database().ref("NotifTimeline").child(uuid).child(newCommentUID + ":" + randID).child("NewComment")

  notifTimelineRef.set(newCommentUID)//update
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Success updating this uid comment timeline")
  })
  .catch((error: string) => {
    console.log("Error in catch: "+error)
    response.status(500).send(error)
  })
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `Promise.resolve()` instead of the promise returned by `notifTimelineRef.set()`?  The function needs to know to wait until *that* promise is resolved.

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing, how do I return a promise which is returned by the .set()?

Comment: I think it because of your `const uid = context.params.uid`. I don't see any param name `uid` in your `ref`.

Comment: This was it. @ToraCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToraCode got it right in his comment when he said:

> I think it because of your const uid = context.params.uid. I don't see any param name uid in your ref

Answer (score 0):

Return the promise that was returned by set():

```
function addNewCommentNotif(uuid: string, newCommentUID: string) {

  //NotifTimeline/uid/NewNotif (someuniqueVal)/commentID
  const randID = Math.floor(100000000 + Math.random() * 900000000);
  const notifTimelineRef = admin.database().ref("NotifTimeline").child(uuid).child(newCommentUID + ":" + randID).child("NewComment")

  return notifTimelineRef.set(newCommentUID)//update
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Success updating this uid comment timeline")
  })
  .catch((error: string) => {
    console.log("Error in catch: "+error)
    response.status(500).send(error)
  })
}
```